# Синонім до слова "ракушка"

Tags: синоніми, іменники

Цікавить синоніми до слова "ракушка". В контексті: "Люблю на березі моря збирати ракушки".

Саме слово "ракушка" є в СУМ, але з позначкою діалектне

> [Ракушка](http://sum.in.ua/s/rakushka) и, жін., діал. Черепашка (у 1, 2 знач.).
>
> [Черепашка](http://sum.in.ua/s/cherepashka) *1.Загальновживана назва слимаків, молюсків і т. ін. із
> стулчастим або іншим твердим захисним покриттям.
> 2. Тверде захисне покриття деяких безхребетних тварин (слимаків, молюсків і т. ін.) у вигляді стулок або витої коробочки.* //  Стулки,
> уламки стулок з такого покриття. //  збірн. Скупчення, поклади в
> якомусь місці такого твердого покриття та його уламків.
>
> 3. ент. Невелика хоботна комаха, що є небезпечним шкідником злакових культур.
> 4. Зменш.-пестл. до черепаха.

Якщо замінити слово *"ракушка"* на *"черепашка"* не зовсім зрозуміло, що саме збираєш.

Яким не діалетним словом (синонім) замінити ***"ракушка"***, в значенні *"тверде захисне покриття деяких безхребетних тварин (слимаків, молюсків і т. ін.) у вигляді стулок або витої коробочки."*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Думаю, Вам може підійти слово "мушля" - це той самий захисний скелетний утвір, що вкриває тіло багатьох молюсків, плечоногих та деяких ракоподібних. Згідно з [СУМ](http://sum.in.ua/s/mushlja), мушля є синонімом до "черепашка".